# Exchange ID token for self-signed access token in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-web

I am using Azure AD for authentication. I am able to get an identification token and information about the user like this:

```
// Add default authentication scheme
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        configureOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        configureOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

// Add my own JWT handler
authenticationBuilder.AddScheme<MyOwnJwtBearerAuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyOwnJwtBearerAuthenticationHandler>(
        MyOwnJwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        configureOptions =>
        {
            //Some config goes here
        }
    );

authenticationBuilder.AddCookie();

string oidcInstance = configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]!;
string oidcDomain = configuration["AzureAd:Domain"]!;
string oidcClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]!;
string oidcTenantId = configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]!;
string oidcClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]!;

authenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = $https://login.microsoftonline.com/{oidcTenantId}/v2.0/;
        options.ClientId = oidcClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = oidcClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(oidcInstance).Validate;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = userInformationReceivedContext =>
        {
            //Get infor about the user
            if (userInformationReceivedContext.Principal is { })
            {
                System.Security.Claims.Claim? userIdClaim = userInformationReceivedContext.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Type == "preferred_username");

                if (userIdClaim is null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Identity token from Azure AD does not contain an expected claim 'preferred_username'.");
                }

                // HERE I HAVE ALL I NEED TO GENERATE AN ACCESS TOKEN
                // BUT THIS IS THE WRONG PLACE
                int lifetimeInMinutes = 5;

                string jwt = MyTokenRules.GenerateJwt(userId: userIdClaim.Value, issuer: jwtSettings.Issuer, audience: jwtSettings.Audience, key: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(jwtSettings.SecretKeyName) ?? String.Empty, duration: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(lifetimeInMinutes));
           }

           return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

Where do I "exchange" identification token for my own self-signed access token which will live in the browser (probably in a cookie)? I say "exchange" because some information from the identification token will need to be passed to the access token such as the "preferred_username" claim which will become the "sub" claim in the access token.